# Batch file not working when using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks, azure

I have a very simple batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
subst s: .
TIMEOUT 10
S:\System\App\System.exe
```

It is located on an AZURE VM that starts every day at a specific time. I have created a scheduled task to run this batch file on startup.

If I run the batch it works fine

It does not work through the Task Scheduler.
Not on startup and not even once I am logged in and I click Run or set the trigger to a certain time.
I have directed the output into a log file and this is what I get:

```
Waiting for 10 seconds, press a key to continue ... 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

This means the "subst s: ." was executed but the S drive is not created.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: My first guess is that you don't have permission when running the task.  What account are you running it from?  Does this account have the right do do what you intend?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have only one acount on that VM. I noticed that if I change it to run only when user is logged in it works. once I change to run whether user is logged in or not it does not.

Comment: And under "Security Options".. is "Run whether use is logged in or not" seclected?  Have you tried checking the "Run with highest privileges" box?

Comment: I suspect it's the age of UAC problem, when you map a drive as a non-elevated prompt you can't see it in an elevated prompt and visa versa.  Hence `EnableLinkedConnections` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command  I assume either the scheduled task is elevated and the other session isn't or the other way around.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Run whether user is logged in or not is selected and also Run with highest privilages as well

Comment: Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746471/batch-files-with-timeout-with-no-press-any-key-to-continue). You should try (timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK > nul)